# Docusign - Prepopulate Template Fields

Tags: python, docusignapi

So I'm battling with the DocuSign API at the moment.
I've created a template with a single e-Tab, called "test"

[image]

I'd like to send off a JSON request that will trigger a signing response.  Part of this request will contain pre-set values specific to the client.

So far, I can get everything to work (sending the email to the correct address etc) except my request structure isn't correctly mapping the value to the field.

The request:

```
request = json.dumps({'accountId': account_id,
                      'status': 'sent',
                      'emailSubject': 'You have a document you need to sign',
                      'emailBlurb': 'This is a blurb',
                      'templateId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                      'customFields': {
                          'textCustomFields': [{
                              'name': 'address',
                              'required': 'True',
                              'show': 'True',
                              'value': 'This is an address'
                          }],
                      },
                      'templateRoles': [{
                          'email': 'my_email@emailsrus.com',
                          'name': 'Jamie Strauss',
                          'roleName': 'Signer1',
                          'recipientId': '1',
                          "tabs": {
                              "textTabs": [{
                                  "tabLabel": "test",
                                  "value": "hello123",
                              }]
                          },
                      }],
                      })
```

The email comes through, but when I navigate into the docusign endpoint the rendered field is blank.

[image]

I have tried variable implementations of the "tab" settings to no avail.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you created the "test" text tab for the recipient "Steven Johns" but your API call is referring to the "Signer1" role.

Check that the tab is associated with the Signer1 role/recipient.

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for using DocuSign.